# Getting id from ImageView and if the getId then compare with with specific ImageView id?

Tags: javafx-8

I am able the get the id of `ImageView` by using

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView)event.getSource();
```

and storing in the string

```
String userClickedImage = iv.getId();
```

but you I can compare with the id that I already gave to `ImageView` in fxml
In fxml file I  have three Images with three different ids.as can see below

```xml
<ImageView fx:id="iv_Rock" fitHeight="100" fitWidth="100"
           onMouseClicked="#selectImage"
           GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="2" >
    <image >
        <Image url="@images/Rock.jpg"  />
    </image>
</ImageView>
```

and How I compare

```
iv.getId().equals(iv_Rock)
```

is not working when I click on rock image it should it give the result but it is not showing me the result.

Answer (score 0):

The `id` property contains a string. For this reason the correct way to compare the id would be

```
iv.getId().equals("iv_Rock")
```

Since you seem to inject the `ImageView` to the controller though, simply comparing the references should also work:

```
event.getSource() == iv_Rock
```

---

You should consider simply using 3 different event handler methods though. This would remove the need of checking the source; Usually it's not a good idea to use the same event handler method for completely unrelated things based on the source.